# Why does Wolfram Alpha mess up $\int \sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t)dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

If you enter ["\int \sin(pi t)\cos(pi t)dt"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+sin%28pi+t%29cos%28pi+t%29dt) into Wolfram Alpha, it yields the result $-\frac{\cos^2(\pi t)}{2 \pi}$ which is obviously false, since integrals can't be negative (right?) In fact the correct answer is $\frac{\sin^2(\pi t)}{2\pi}$.

The way I found this was by choosing $\sin(\pi t)$ as $u$, leaving $\pi \cos(\pi t)$ as $du$ and integrating $\frac{1}{\pi}\int udu$ to $\frac{u^2}{2 \pi}$ which turns back into $\frac{\sin^2(\pi t)}{2\pi}$.

It seems that Wolfram Alpha chose $cos(\pi t)$ as $u$, which led to the negative result. But $-\frac{\cos^2(\pi t)}{2 \pi} \ne \frac{\sin^2(\pi t)}{2\pi}$.

My question is, how or why can the choice of $u$ lead to different results when integrating?

EDIT: Of course integrals of functions can be negative. I was just remembering my teacher saying that definite integrals must be positive if the function is positive on the interval, which clearly isn't the case here. Sorry.

Comment: Why can't integrals be negative? And also, note that your solution and WolframAlpha's are identical up to a constant, as $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$.

Comment: Differentiate and you will see it is right, almost. So is yours. If you are reporting correctly, you both left out the $+C$.

Comment: As another example, consider $\int \frac 1{x^2}dx$

Comment: An indefinite integral of a continuous function f is ANY function F satisfying F'=f.  If F is one then so is k+F for any constant k. And BTW $\int e^{-x}dx=-e^{-x}$.

Comment: An integral is negative if the area "under" the `x` axis is greater than the area above it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\int\sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t)\,dt=
\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(2\pi t)\,dt=-\frac{\cos(2\pi t)}{4\pi}+c
$$
Just check the derivative.

Now you can expand $\cos(2\pi t)$ as
$$
\cos(2\pi t)=2\cos^2(\pi t)-1=1-2\sin^2(\pi t)
$$
and get both forms. None is “the right one”, both are correct. Functions which differ by a constant have the same derivative.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I think I was remembering my teacher saying the integral must be positive if the function was positive across the integral, but obviously that's not the case here. Sorry.

Comment: @lerenard No, that's incorrect either. The function $f(x)=1$ is positive on the interval $[0,1]$, but an antiderivative is $x-1000$, which is of course negative on $[0,1]$.

Comment: right, because it only applies to definite integrals?

Comment: @lerenard Yes, that's the key!

Answer (score 0):

Notice, both the results obtained are really same just need to manipulate as follows   $$\int \sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t)\ dt$$ $$=\int \frac{1}{2}(2\sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t))\ dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(2\pi t)\ dt $$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi}\cos (2\pi t)\right)+c$$
$$=-\frac{2\cos^2(\pi t)-1}{4\pi}+c$$
$$=-\frac{2\cos^2(\pi t)}{4\pi}+\frac{1}{4\pi}+c$$
substituting a new constant $\frac{1}{4\pi}+c=C$, 
$$=-\frac{\cos^2(\pi t)}{2\pi}+C$$